# How to do a HTTP DELETE request with Requests library

Tags: python, django, httprequest

I'm using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) package for interacting with the toggl.com API.

I can perform GET and POST requests:

```
    payload = {'some':'data'}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    url = "https://www.toggl.com/api/v6/" + data_description + ".json"
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(toggl_token, 'api_token'))
```

but i cant seem to find a way to perform a DELETE request. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use [requests.delete](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=delete#requests.delete) instead of `requests.post`

```py
payload = {'some':'data'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "https://www.toggl.com/api/v6/" + data_description + ".json"

response = requests.delete(
    url, 
    data=json.dumps(payload), 
    headers=headers,
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(toggl_token, 'api_token')
)
```

Comment: what will the "data" Parameter do in a delete request?  can we have conditional delete using the "data" parameter!

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
url = 'url.example.ap'
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---- ",
    'X-Auth-Token': ""anytoken"",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }
r = requests.delete(url, headers=headers)
n = os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), r.content)
print r.content == r.text
```