# How to delete SSRS report files from specific folders in Report Server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sqlreportingservice

I have to delete around 200 SSRS Reports from different folders in Report Server. DBA advised us not to use SQL script on Report Server database, which is not recommended. Is there any way to delete rdls from Report Server other than manually delete reports one by one from Report Server UI. They are recommending us to write some python script for this, but have no idea where to start.
Please help.

Comment: I have used reportservice SOAP api from C# to manage reports and subscriptions. May be you can use it with Python. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005?view=sqlserver-2016

Comment: 200 RDL's across how many folders?Although it's a manual deletion, you can switch view in report manager from tile view to details view which allows you to select all RDL's in the folder at once and delete them all.  If your 200 are only spread across a few folders this will only be a few seconds, but if a lot of folders then not so good.

Comment: i dont know using python! but if you want .net code (rss) then let me know :)

Comment: You could use [rest api](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0) to delete the rdl file in the report server . seems it would get achieved via [send http delete request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191733/how-to-do-a-http-delete-request-with-requests-library) to report server  in python.